# Magento 2 Custom Customer Attribute not Displaying

Tags: magento, magento2

I have been attempting to create a custom customer attribute that would allow the customer to save an attribute to their profile. When I update my **Magento** site with the code, I see no front end change nor do I see any update in my Database. What am I doing incorrectly that is causing both of these issues? Do I need to add some .phtml change?

**InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace SR\DeliveryDate\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

   

     /**
         * @var CustomerSetupFactory
         */
        protected $customerSetupFactory;
    
        /**
         * @var AttributeSetFactory
         */
        private $attributeSetFactory;
    
        /**
         * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
         * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
            AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
        ) {
            $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
            $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        }
    
    
        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
    
            /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    
            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    
            /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
    
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Custom Attributeeee',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position' =>999,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);
    
            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_address_edit'],//you can use other forms also ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
            ]);
    
            $attribute->save();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following commands after you make any major changes to your code. For example, if you create an extension, you might run the upgrade command.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:clean or php bin/magento cache:flush
```

The above commands should be run in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
\magento2\app\code\Custom\CustomerAttribute\Block\Widget\Passport.php
/**
 * @return bool
 */
 
public function isEnabled() {
    $attributeMetadata = $this->_getAttribute('passport');
    return $attributeMetadata ? (bool) $attributeMetadata->isVisible() : false;
}
```